# Android app much, much slower on Galaxy S 4

Tags: android, galaxy

My Android App is very slow on the Galaxy S4. And for SLOW I mean, 10 - 20 times slower than it is on a Galaxy SII... the weird thing it's that it is fast enough on the S2, galaxy tab 10.1, galaxy note 10.1 and a bunch of other samsung devices; it is perceptibly slower on the S3, and VERY slower on the S4...

It's a big app that uses a lot of animations and loads a lot of images from the assets folder and scales them...

I know that what I wrote it's not very helpful... did somebody get the same issue on some app?

Comment: Did you try and profile it? See what takes up the most time?

Comment: Specifically, use Traceview to figure out where your time is being spent.

Answer (score 1):

No experience with the specific Galaxy S4. But what you can do to find potential issues is to check the `Show GPU overdraw` setting in developer settings. It shows areas that are drawn multiple times, which is very slow.

Besides that, check the [hierarchy viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) to see if your layout trees are too deep, [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) to see if you are blocking the UI thread, and [lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/) to do static code analysis for general problems.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem: I don't know why but it slows when it loads images from the assets folder... it works really smooth if I put all those images in the drawable folder. The problem, now, is that i can't do it because my app will download the images from the internet (it will download a zip and put the images in a folder of the application).

Will try something else...

EDIT:

I am now using [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for android and it works really smooth... recommended!!!